# Video cropping when trying to play video in Fullscreen in Chrome?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, video, fullscreen

I am trying to create a responsive video gallery to showcase my work.

I have started using a free template from another site and customising it to use for video however when in chrome there appears to be an issue with the video cropping itself when in fullscreen. (screenshots in chrome and safari respectively)
[Video Fullscreen Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ2IM.png)
[Video Fullscreen Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riNpi.png)

```
<div class=" Portfolio-box printdesign">
<a href="#"><video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="video/RIO%20Round%20Up%20Day%2015_05.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></a>
```

I sourced the template from here https://bootstrapmade.com/knight-free-bootstrap-theme/?download_theme=knight.zip if you need to take a look at the CSS aswell.

I would like to be able to have videos play in fullscreen in both browsers either like the screenshot in Safari but prefarbly the whole screen. Thanks :)

Comment: it will be better if you could create a working fiddle

Comment: Remove the `<a>` that's wrapped around the `<video>` tag.